# materialize and foldLeft with Observable in Scala

Tags: scala

Why this code never fires the subscription block?

```
Observable(1, 2, 3).materialize.foldLeft(0) { (acc, tn) =>
  tn match {
    case OnNext(n) => { println(acc, n); acc + n }
  }
}.subscribe({s => println("THIS IS NOT FIRED", s) })
```

This is the output:
`(0,1)
(1,2)
(3,3)`

Comment: This looks like a homework question from https://class.coursera.org/reactive-001/ and should probably be deleted?

Comment: @jabley You're right! I'm going to delete my answer and post another one more generic.

Answer (score 0):

I am a Scala beginner as well, so bear with me if anything is not explained properly.
It seems that you are missing the `onCompleted` case:

Try it with:

```
 Observable(1, 2, 3).materialize.foldLeft(0) { (acc, tn) =>
   tn match {
   case Notification.OnNext(n)  => { println(acc, n); acc + n }
   case Notification.OnCompleted() => acc
  }
}.subscribe({s => println("THIS IS NOW FIRED", s) })
```

But since the value returned from foldLeft is essentially one (the sum), it'd become more readable if we rewrite it as follows:

```
   val sum = Observable(1, 2, 3).materialize.foldLeft(0) { (acc, tn) =>
       tn match {
       case Notification.OnNext(n)  => { println(acc, n); acc + n }
       case Notification.OnCompleted() => acc
      }
    }.toBlockingObservable.single

   println(sum) // prints 6
```

Needless to say that the previous solutions hold True only for cases where there is no element in the stream that raises an Error.

I found [this link](https://github.com/Netflix/RxJava/blob/master/language-adaptors/rxjava-scala/src/examples/scala/rx/lang/scala/examples/RxScalaDemo.scala) very helpful to understand Observables.